# ngrx/component-store trigger effect when state changes

Tags: ngrx-store, component-store

I have an angular app with `@ngrx/component-store`.

when the user selects an entry from a list of devices, I store this into `component-store`

```
  component.ts:
  onDeviceClicked(device: DeviceTO) {
    this.inspectionStore.setDeviceSelected(device);
  }

  inspectionStore.ts
  readonly setDeviceSelected = (data: DeviceTO) =>  {this.patchState({selectedDevice: data})};
```

Now, that the user has selected a device, a side effect should be triggered. However I am not sure how I can trigger a side effect when part of the state changed.

Do I need to do it when updating state?

```
  readonly setDeviceSelected = (data: DeviceTO) =>  {
    this.patchState({selectedDevice: data});
    this.tiggerMySideEffect(data);
  };
```

Or is there another way I can tell the sideEffect to listen for changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since an effect is automatically subscribed to, one does not need an external trigger (by calling the effect explicitly). The effect can directly react to the state-change. So the following (as an example) does work:

```
public readonly selectedDevice$ = this.select(({ selectedDevice }) => selectedDevice);

private readonly effectOnSelectedDevice = this.effect(_ => this.selectedDevice$.pipe(switchMap(selectedDevice => this.service.doSideEffect(selectedDevice))));
```

Any observable can be used here (e.g. `this.store` or a combination with `combineLatest`, etc).

To go a step further, you could have a chain of effects (hidden from the outside) - that react on state-changes performed by a previous effect to refine data (doing different calls to backends).

None of them would need an explicit, manual trigger.

Comment: hi mate! where do you call effectOnSelectedDevice? in the constructor?

Comment: @valeriocomo it's the field's definition, as you can see by the `private readonly`.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire the effect from onDeviceClicked right after updating the state.

Example with a similar case: https://next.ngrx.io/generated/live-examples/component-store-slide-toggle/stackblitz.html

Guide: https://next.ngrx.io/guide/component-store/usage

Comment: i want to trigger the effect everytime the selectedDevice state changes. if someone else changes it I also want to trigger the effect

Comment: What do you mean by "someone else changes it"?

Answer (score 0):

Sample code

Selector:

```
public readonly filter$ = this.select(({ filter }) => filter);
```

Subscription:

```
public ngrxOnStateInit(): void {
    this.filter$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$), debounceTime(17)).subscribe(() => this.myEffect());
}
```

Then you can trigger state change inside an effect like this

[image]